# kubernetes e2e tests fails with spec.configSource: Invalid value

Tags: testing, kubernetes

We are running kubernetes(1.15.3) e2e tests via sonobuoy and 3 of them fail with the same error:

```
/go/src/k8s-tests/test/e2e/framework/framework.go:674
error setting labels on node
Expected error:
    <*errors.StatusError | 0xc001e6def0>: {
        ErrStatus: {
            TypeMeta: {Kind: "", APIVersion: ""},
            ListMeta: {SelfLink: "", ResourceVersion: "", Continue: ""},
            Status: "Failure",
            Message: "Node \"nightly-e2e-rhel76-1vm\" is invalid: spec.configSource: Invalid value: core.NodeConfigSource{ConfigMap:(*core.ConfigMapNodeConfigSource)(nil)}: exactly one reference subfield must be non-nil",
            Reason: "Invalid",
            Details: {
                Name: "nightly-e2e-rhel76-1vm",
                Group: "",
                Kind: "Node",
                UID: "",
                Causes: [
                    {
                        Type: "FieldValueInvalid",
                        Message: "Invalid value: core.NodeConfigSource{ConfigMap:(*core.ConfigMapNodeConfigSource)(nil)}: exactly one reference subfield must be non-nil",
                        Field: "spec.configSource",
                    },
                ],
                RetryAfterSeconds: 0,
            },
            Code: 422,
        },
    }
    Node "nightly-e2e-rhel76-1vm" is invalid: spec.configSource: Invalid value: core.NodeConfigSource{ConfigMap:(*core.ConfigMapNodeConfigSource)(nil)}: exactly one reference subfield must be non-nil
not to have occurred
/go/src/k8s-tests/test/e2e/apps/daemon_set.go:170
```

kubectl get nodes -o yaml gives these fields and yes, we do have kubelet dynamic config enabled:

```
spec:
  configSource:
    configMap:
      kubeletConfigKey: kubelet
      name: kubelet-config-1.15.3-1581671888
      namespace: kube-system
```

[cloud-user@nightly-e2e-rhel76-1vm ~]$ kubectl get no nightly-e2e-rhel76-1vm -o json  | jq .status.config

```
{
  "active": {
    "configMap": {
      "kubeletConfigKey": "kubelet",
      "name": "kubelet-config-1.15.3-1581671888",
      "namespace": "kube-system",
      "resourceVersion": "508",
      "uid": "71961ed7-2fff-41f5-80b7-78167fb056fc"
    }
  },
  "assigned": {
    "configMap": {
      "kubeletConfigKey": "kubelet",
      "name": "kubelet-config-1.15.3-1581671888",
      "namespace": "kube-system",
      "resourceVersion": "508",
      "uid": "71961ed7-2fff-41f5-80b7-78167fb056fc"
    }
  },
  "lastKnownGood": {
    "configMap": {
      "kubeletConfigKey": "kubelet",
      "name": "kubelet-config-1.15.3-1581671888",
      "namespace": "kube-system",
      "resourceVersion": "508",
      "uid": "71961ed7-2fff-41f5-80b7-78167fb056fc"
    }
  }
}
```

What are we missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Check with `kubectl get no ${NODE_NAME} -o json | jq '.status.config`

Comment: I'm not familiar with Sonobuoy, you might have a better change getting help at [slack #sonobuoy​](https://kubernetes.slack.com/messages/sonobuoy) or [“Help wanted”](https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/sonobuoy/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3A%22Help+wanted%22+).